# Excel/VBA - Run-time error 91 only occurs after entering and leaving the design mode

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, userform

I have to fix a bug in a excel file with lots of vba macros which I didn't create. Also I've never worked with VBA in Excel so I hope you can help me a out a bit.

The file is used to store all kind of information in each row and there is a button that shows/pop ups a user form where I can edit a new row and atferwards add it to the file.
Everything works fine, I open the file and I can use it as intended.
But after I entered and left the Desing mode, everytime I hit that "new row" button I get a run-time error 91.

When I debug it, the debugger stops at a line where I want to write the user name from a variable(the name is stored on opening of the file) into a text file.

`Print #file, user.name`

After hardcoding the user name(`Print #file, "ck"`) the debugger stops at different position with run-time error 91 where the user form is loaded/shown.

`frmAddData.Show`

In my understanding this error occurs because the `user.name` and `frmAddData` are both empty respectively deleted after I left the edit mode.

Are there any known issues or has anyone ever heard of such a issue with the desing mode or has someone a idea what kind of bug/error or what ever can cause this strange problem and how to fix it without rewriting the whole thing?

Thank you in advance,
Gistiv

Comment: Design mode will sometimes cause code to be recompiled, so any related variables may be lost/cleared.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to stop this or at least to know how and which code is recompiled?

Comment: No real way to stop it I think - if you edit code then that's going to have some effect if you've already got objects created based off that code.  In a regular module you're likely safe, but if you're editing a class module (form/worksheet/custom class) you will see the behavior you're having problems with.

Comment: The error occurs even if Ido nothing in the desing mode. I only push the button for the mode twice(to enter and instant leave) and it stops working....

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278684.aspx - exiting Design mode "clears all module level variables in the project" so you may be stuck with this behavior

Comment: Thank you for your help! This seems to be te reason. I will go after it and hopfuly theres a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a real solution to this so I deleted the design mode button in the menu so no one is able to enter it. Just securing the file with a password didn't disable the design mode so this was the only quick solution I could find.